# Accessing c/c++ level of swig wrapped object from cython

Tags: python, c++, numpy, swig, cython

Ok first I know that generally this isn't something you should try to do however, I have a large C/C++ libary with a swig wrapper (Third party) that I'm using for solving a problem by time stepping, I need to dump data each step, however the libaries existing data dumping functions are basicly a load of crap and aren't even readable. However I can access the data I need by a look up function however I'm looking at fields of data the function is C/C++ level and accepts at point and paramater, and returns the field at that location.

I can call this from python using the swig wrapper on the class, however I need to call it 768 000 times for a simple test problem per time step, this means that rahter the 360 steps in 1.5s, each time step is taking 120-180s.

On the otherhand the calls are simply setting array elements in a numpy/h5py array I want to rewrite this to use cython, (I known exactly how to do it given I was wraping the whole libary myself from cython and had access to the C level object) so I need to access this C function and C resprestation of the object (my problem) from cython. (http://docs.cython.org/src/userguide/wrapping_CPlusPlus.html)

However I'm not really familur with swig as I don't use it I use either C-API or cython for interfacing code, I also can't find any obvious information on the internet, so short of spending a couple of months dicescting swig I can't solve this myself, I have looked at the swig generated files and they are full of junk which makes them impossible to follow.

Say I have python wrapper object X with python wrapper method y(*args) which wraps c object cX and method call cX.y, how can I get a refrence to cX from X so I can use somthing allong the lines of the following to inspect the fields:

```
cdef extern from "X.h" namespace "N":
    cdef cppclass cX:
        R y(T1 arg1, T2 arg2)

cpdef get_fields(X /*swig wrapper class */, ndarray points):
     buffer /* python buffer object */
     for j in range(J):
         for i in range(I):
             for k in range(K):
                 p = points[j,i,k]
                 buffer[j,i,k] = get_cX(X).y(arg1, T2(p[0],p[1],[3]))
     return buffer
```

What would the function get_cX(X) be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Extracting SWIG wrapped C++ instance/pointer for use in Cython](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904033/extracting-swig-wrapped-c-instance-pointer-for-use-in-cython)

Comment: See also https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cython-users/YPzCqO4jxlA